# How do I change the color of an element via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is driving me crazy.  I think I have everything right but I am unable to change the color via jQuery.  I first was doing this locally then I thought that jQuery can't be used locally, which I learned was incorrect but to make it work I uploaded to my server and it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Test</title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <script>
          $("p").css('color', 'blue');
     </script>
     <p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only forgot to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("p").css('color', 'blue');
})
```

[**See it Working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/739qm/1/)

Comment: I made a rookie mistake! the tutorial i am watching didn't do this at all so I thought we could work with it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").css('color', 'blue');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/xK4Yf/)

[**.ready()**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> Description: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully
>   loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").css('color', 'blue');
});
```

Comment: I made a rookie mistake! the tutorial i am watching didn't do this at all so I thought we could work with it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .[Refer](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").css('color', 'blue');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in `document.ready` function, Like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").css('color', 'blue');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions are perfect  here is the reason why ? ?

> in java script every function is called when event occurs in jquery the first event is on load event when the the code is ready to execute ready event is fired all the functions have to be called with in these ready event only